# При обновлении версии градл до 3.1.2 получаю ошибку

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle

Сейчас использую в проекте градл версии `2.3.2` - все работает

Если обновляю версию до `3.1.2` то сначала студия просит обновить версию тулов

```
Update Build Tools version and sync project
```

Нажимаю ОК

и в итоге получаю ошибку

```
error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found.  
error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowExitAnimation' not found.   

error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute 
'@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found., sources= 
[C:\Users\myuser\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7- 
27.1.1.aar\6320998e25142e55f50961eb6b498b4c\res\values\values.xml:1586:5- 
 1587:13], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

Я читал несколько постов как этот

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952607/error-style-attribute-androidattr-windowexitanimation-not-found?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

но у меня в стилях нет дополнительных символов как этот `@`

Не пойму, что он хочет

Если чего то забыл добавить в вопрос , говорите добавлю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте папку `gradle` удалить и заново сбилдить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло